# Setting up React with Grails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grails, webpack, bundle

I'm currently working on integrating React with Grails (2.3.11). It seems however that even the most basic setup is giving me a hard time. I've set up my file and folder structure that I have done before with past projects but my bundle.js file just doesn't seem to be want to be found. I keep getting a 404 no matter how many different times I change the path.

[This is basically what happens all the time!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie3gt.png)

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "react_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Grails with React",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  },
}
```

My root.gsp file that is supposed to pick up the bundle.js file and render the react code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grails with React</title>
    <script src="../../../src/react/public/bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <p>React broke down</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Webpack file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/react/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/react/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/main.jsx',
  mode : 'development',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'env']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", '.jsx', '*']
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Finally here's my simple starting file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p> Hello, World!</p>;
  }
}
render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[If it helps, here's my folder structure!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc4cq.png)

Any advice or help you can throw my away is greatly appreciated! I'd be willing to experiment! Thank you!

Comment: What is the reason to use both gsp and react? Better to keep react frontend separate from grails api.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation I discovered what needed to be done. Because this is a Grails application it has be written very specifically and has to be outputted in the correct folder.

Change the script line into this:

```
<g:javascript src="bundle.js"></g:javascript>
```

Then make sure to output the bundle.js file in the web-app/js folder. This is a must. So change your webpack to this:

```
var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'web-app/js');
```

That solved it!